# Click a QPushbutton in a QWidget will cause focusOutEvent, how to ignore this?

Tags: qwidget, qpushbutton, slot, focusout

In my code when `focusOutEvent` slot calls, this widget will be closed. While, I came cross a problem that click a `QPushbutton` in this current widget will also cause `focusOutEvent` and button `clicked()` signal can never be triggered any more.

In construct function:
`connect(btn, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(btnClickFucntion()));`
then, I have function like following:

```
void AWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    Q_UNUSED(event);
    this->close();
}

void AWidget::focusOutEvent(QFocusEvent *event)
{
    if (!this->isHidden())
    {
        event->accept();
        this->close();
    }
    else
        event->ignore();
}

void AWidget::btnClickFucntion()
{
    //Do something
}
```

However, `btnClickFucntion{}` never called.

Comment: btn's parent widget is AWidget

Answer (score 0):

```
bool AWidget::isFocusChange2BtnInside()
{
    QPushButton *btn = dynamic_cast<QPushButton *>(this->focusWidget());
    if (btn == this->btn)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I add this function as a condition(if true, return; else go next step) before calling `close()` function, and fix it.
Sorry to bother.

Comment: short way: `bool AWidget::isFocusChange2BtnInside(){return btn == focusWidget(); }`

Comment: Yeah, this is more concise. Thanks for that.